# Knowing if php script is submitted to an output redirection

Tags: php, bash, command-line

I have a php script which is run in the terminal and it returns a number the number is human-friendly formated so :

```
php script.php
```

will for example output: 1 020 536

But sometimes we need this script to output the number as a computer-friendly version so in my case :

1020536

Is it possible to detect directly from the php script if it's called directly or in the following ways :

```
echo $(php script.php)
```

and

```
php script.php | cat
```

The both version should output the number non formated.

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: couldn't you use a parameter to define weather it should be formated human or machine friendly? That would make the bahaviour of said script more predictable. Which is a good thing if it comes to scripts isn't it? Contrary to movies and books? ;D

Comment: I could but I would really prefer to do it the way I asked ^^

Comment: please upload your php file

Comment: you could add an init set to just that file. i.e. `ini_set('memory_limit','1GB');`

Comment: @Babby my php script is not needed (it's not relevant) I just need a condition to know wether or not my script is called directly or though one of two other ways I have described.

@ Andresch Serj I think you didn't understand my question. It has nothing to dot with the memory limit.

Comment: @MyWetSocks you can do that with `posix_isatty`. See my answer for further detail

Comment: @MyWetSocks : what is output this command `php script.php|xxd`

Comment: i didnt get your question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [posix-isatty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-isatty.php). Here is an example;

in your `script.php` you can implement;

```
<?php

if ( !posix_isatty(STDOUT) ) {
    fwrite(STDOUT, "You piped this script to another command");
    exit(2);
}
fwrite(STDOUT, "Called directly");

exit(0);

?>
```

**Update:** Just for the incomers:

`posix_isatty` helps you to detect if script output piped to elsewhere or not. In case above, `posix_isatty(STDOUT)` means, your php script outputs to terminal. If you pipe your php script like `php script | cat`, `posix_isatty(STDOUT)` will be `false`. Because, you have redirected output of your script to `cat` as input. In other words, you redirected your script output to place that is not an terminal.

Comment: Can you tell me what this function do ?..i didnt get anything from the manual

Comment: @CodeLover I have updated my answer for further detail. If you have any other questions, do not hesitate to ask. Thanks